# Как разбить объект на параметры для отправки POST запросом через AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
let title = 'Test';
let name = 'test';
let position = 25;

let send = {
  title: title,
  name: name,
  position: position,
};

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/terminal', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(xhr.response);
}
xhr.send(`title=${title}&name=${name}&position=${position}`); // Работает
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(send)); // Не работает, не в том виде отправляет
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Object.entries(send).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`).join('&')
```

---

```js
let title = 'Test';
let name = 'test';
let position = 25;
let send = {
  title: title,
  name: name,
  position: position,
};

let sendAsGetParams = Object.entries(send).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`).join('&');

console.log(sendAsGetParams);
```

---

ещё вариант, попроще:

```
new URLSearchParams(send).toString();
```

```js
let title = 'Test';
let name = 'test';
let position = 25;
let send = {
  title: title,
  name: name,
  position: position,
};

console.log(new URLSearchParams(send).toString());
```